# What is the best way to conduct English word-recall exercises with people who have just been exposed to English via GUI elements?

Tags: user-research, wording, content, localization

I'm working on an App for Indian languages and the users in context have heard English very little. Only for things like 'Tables', 'Order', etc. I wanted to understand what's a good way to conduct word and iconography recall exercises of one language in non-native speakers of that language.

Comment: I would look at the application Duolingo for some inspiration for this sort of thing. They are the name brand for introducing people to new languages in a simple and efficient way.

Comment: @LeviJ (As a linguist by formal education) I agree! Elaborate an answer below with some pictures.